# How to disconnect from MongoDB in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I am trying to write a Perl5 script that checks the status of a MongoDB server every minute and notifies me if it is down. Any suggestion is welcome for this task. Currently, I am using 'MongoDB' module and 'MongoDB::MongoClient' to establish a connection to see if server is available. Here is the basic idea:

```
while(1)
{
        my $conn = connectMongoDB();

        if($conn){
                sleep 60;
        }   
        else{
                sendMail();
                last;
        }   
}

sub connectMongoDB
{
        my $client;

        eval{ $client =  MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => "mongodb://:\@$server");};

        return ($client)?1:0;       
}
```

The main problem is that there is no way to disconnect from the server. Here is what it says on the cpan page:

"There is no way to explicitly disconnect from the database. However, the connection will automatically be closed and cleaned up when no references to the MongoDB::MongoClient object exist, which occurs when $client goes out of scope (or earlier if you undefine it with undef)."

I tried 'undef' and subroutines. None of them terminates the connection. Because of the loop, the number of connections keep increasing. Is there any other method I can try to keep the number of connections under control?

Any other suggestion for tackling this issue is appreciated as long as it doesn't involve crontab.

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is the output when sleep time is set to 2 secs where db version is v2.4.4 and MongoDB module version is 0.701.4. The problem persists after upgrading MongoDB module to 0.702.1.

```
Fri Aug 16 20:33:06.986 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51031 #3 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:08.989 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51033 #4 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:10.991 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51034 #5 (3 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:12.994 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51035 #6 (4 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:14.996 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51036 #7 (5 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:16.999 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51038 #8 (6 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:19.003 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51039 #9 (7 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:21.006 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51040 #10 (8 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:23.009 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51042 #11 (9 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:25.013 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51043 #12 (10 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:27.016 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51044 #13 (11 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:29.019 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51045 #14 (12 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 20:33:31.022 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51047 #15 (13 connections now open)
```

EDIT 2: SOLVED!!

I believe the problem is related to auto_connect option. Once it is disabled, The code works fine. Below is something that works for now.

```
sub connectMongoDB
{
        my $client;

        eval{
                $client =  MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => "mongodb://:\@$server",
                      auto_connect => 0); 
                $client->connect;
        };  
        return (!$@)?1:0;
}
```

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the subroutine as the following,

```
sub connectMongoDB
{
        my $client;

        eval{
                $client =  MongoDB::MongoClient->new( host => "mongodb://:\@$server",
                      auto_connect => 0); 
                $client->connect;
        };  
        return (!$@)?1:0;
}
```

The problem was the 'auto_reconnect' option all along.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unable to reproduce this problem with MongoDB 2.4.1 and version 0.702.1 of the MongoDB driver from CPAN.

I ran your code with the sleep timeout changed to 10 seconds, connecting to localhost. After running for a couple minutes, running `db.serverStatus()` in the `mongo` shell continued to show just one connection. (That's the connection for the shell session.)

Here's the output from `mongod` showing the connections being opened and closed every ten seconds. (You can see that I fired up the shell after the first two connections cycled.)

```
Fri Aug 16 21:36:43.589 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:57722 (0 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:36:53.526 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57723 #2 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:36:53.527 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:57723 (0 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:36:58.421 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57724 #3 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:03.529 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57725 #4 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:03.529 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:57725 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:13.531 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57726 #5 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:13.532 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:57726 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:23.534 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57727 #6 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:23.535 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:57727 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:33.537 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57728 #7 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:33.538 [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:57728 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:43.540 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57729 #8 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:43.540 [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:57729 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:53.542 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57730 #9 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:37:53.543 [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:57730 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:03.545 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57731 #10 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:03.545 [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:57731 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:13.547 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57732 #11 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:13.548 [conn11] end connection 127.0.0.1:57732 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:23.550 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57734 #12 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:23.550 [conn12] end connection 127.0.0.1:57734 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:33.552 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57735 #13 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:33.553 [conn13] end connection 127.0.0.1:57735 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:43.555 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57736 #14 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:43.555 [conn14] end connection 127.0.0.1:57736 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:53.557 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57737 #15 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:38:53.559 [conn15] end connection 127.0.0.1:57737 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:03.560 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57738 #16 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:03.561 [conn16] end connection 127.0.0.1:57738 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:13.563 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57740 #17 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:13.564 [conn17] end connection 127.0.0.1:57740 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:23.566 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57741 #18 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:23.567 [conn18] end connection 127.0.0.1:57741 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:33.569 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57747 #19 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:33.570 [conn19] end connection 127.0.0.1:57747 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:43.572 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57748 #20 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:43.573 [conn20] end connection 127.0.0.1:57748 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:53.575 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57750 #21 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:39:53.576 [conn21] end connection 127.0.0.1:57750 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:03.579 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57751 #22 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:03.579 [conn22] end connection 127.0.0.1:57751 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:13.580 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57753 #23 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:13.581 [conn23] end connection 127.0.0.1:57753 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:23.584 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57754 #24 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:23.584 [conn24] end connection 127.0.0.1:57754 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:33.586 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57755 #25 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:33.586 [conn25] end connection 127.0.0.1:57755 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:43.588 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57758 #26 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:43.588 [conn26] end connection 127.0.0.1:57758 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:53.590 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57760 #27 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:40:53.591 [conn27] end connection 127.0.0.1:57760 (1 connection now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:41:03.592 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57761 #28 (2 connections now open)
Fri Aug 16 21:41:03.593 [conn28] end connection 127.0.0.1:57761 (1 connection now open)
```

Can you let me know what version of MongoDB (the server) and MongoDB (the driver) you're using?

Comment: @squiguy you must be looking for easy +1's. :)

Comment: No way can I answer this! Just thought I would point that out so he realizes that your answer is from the horse's mouth.

Comment: Will let you know when I check back. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Updated the question answering your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the update @mteg. I'm unsure what would cause that but I should have some more time to investigate later this weekend.

Comment: Please see the solution. It might be useful to fix it. Thanks.